# Basic arithmetic with matrices

Tags: matrices

We have matrices. 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\
-5 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-7 & 8 \\
2 & -8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
C=\begin{bmatrix}
-15 & -2 \\
-8 & -14 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We need to solve matrix $X$ from equation:

$$A^{-1}XB-C=0$$
$$X=AB^{-1}+C$$
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\
-5 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-7 & 8 \\
2 & -8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-15 & -2 \\
-8 & -14 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -18 \\
39 & -102 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This doesn't seem to be correct solutions to this equations ?

Comment: How do you go from $A^{-1}XB=C$ to $X=AB^{-1}+C$?

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-introduction.html may help

Comment: You made a mistake: form $A^{-1}XB=C$ we get $X=ACB^{-1}$.

Comment: This was just a guess based on $Ax=b$ is same as $X=A^{-1}b$

Comment: Since order does matter when you multiply matrices for example $AB \neq BA$. How do you determine order in this. $A^{-1}XB=C$ to $X=ACB^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Also when $C$ is not initially multiplied with $A$ or $B$ how it is multiplied in this $X=ACB^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As point out by you that the order matters:

Pre-multiply and post-multiply are different.

Starting from
$${A^{ - 1}}XB - C = 0$$
Add $C$ on both sides
$${A^{ - 1}}XB = C$$
Now post-multiply by $B^{-1}$ on both sides
$${A^{ - 1}}X{B}{B^{ - 1}} = C{B^{ - 1}}$$
$${A^{ - 1}}X{I} = C{B^{ - 1}}$$
$${A^{ - 1}}X = C{B^{ - 1}}$$
Now pre-multiply by $A$ on both sides to get the final form
$${A}{A^{ - 1}}X = AC{B^{ - 1}}$$
$$X = AC{B^{ - 1}}$$

Comment: One thing i didn't understand is that when you multiply $B^-1$ both sides why do you get $A^{-1}XI=CB^{-1}$. specifically what does $I$ stand for ?

Comment: Perhaps indetity matrix meaning $1$ in diagonal and 0 else where ?

Comment: @Tuki Correct, ${I}$ is the identity matrix with ones on its leading diagnoal and zeros as other elements.

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$X=AB^{-1}+C \tag 1$

does ***not*** follow from

$A^{-1}XB-C= 0; \tag 2$

instead, we have

$A^{-1}XB = C, \tag 3$

$XB = AC,\tag 4$

$X = ACB^{-1}; \tag 5$

if we now perform the indicated matrix arithmetic we arrive at

$X = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ -5 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -15 & -2\\-8 & -14 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -7 & 8 \\ 2 & -8 \end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix} 30 & 4 \\ 27 & -74 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -7 & 8 \\ 2 & -8 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -202 & 208\\ -337 & 808 \\ \end{bmatrix}. \tag 6$

As a check of the above, we see that (1) implies

$A^{-1}XB = A^{-1}(AB^{-1}+C)B = A^{-1}AB^{-1}B + A^{-1}CB = I + A^{-1}CB \ne C \tag 7$

in general.