# Basic arithmetic with matrices round two

Tags: matrices

We have matrices. (Same matrices as in post earlier).
You can find earlier post from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451855/basic-arithmetic-with-matrices).
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\
-5 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-7 & 8 \\
2 & -8 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
C=\begin{bmatrix}
-15 & -2 \\
-8 & -14 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would like to solve $X$ from this equation 
$$CX=-6X+I$$
$$CX+6X=I$$
$$X(C+6)=I$$
Multiplying both sides with $(C+6)^{-1}$
$$XI=I(C+6)^{-1}$$
$$X=(C+6)^{-1}$$
Is this correct ?
$$X=(\begin{bmatrix}
-15 & -2 \\
-8 & -14 \\
\end{bmatrix}+6)^{-1}$$
$$X=(\begin{bmatrix}
-9 & -2 \\
-2 & -8 \\
\end{bmatrix})^-1$$
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{2}{17} & \frac{1}{34} \\
\frac{1}{34} & -\frac{9}{68}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: In general, one way of seeing if you are correct is plugging the matrix back into the equation to see if it works.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative. Do not interchange $CX$ and $XC$.

Comment: Yep i tried plugging in numbers and it seems this is not correct solution indeed.

Comment: Just a silly mistake in adding $6$ 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ll}
 -9 & +4 \\
 -2 & -8 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{10} & -\frac{1}{20} \\
 \frac{1}{40} & -\frac{9}{80} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Is wrong anyway. The actual result is $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{28} \\
 \frac{1}{7} & -\frac{9}{56} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: But is the equation correct ? $X=(C+6)^{-1}$

Comment: It appears that this is correct solution